# Changing the specific item in row in recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How to change specific view in row in `RecyclerView`. `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` or `Adapter.notifyItemChanged` updating row. But I need change the specific view in row, without touching other views in this row.

Comment: View means ? Sorry I ddnt get the question, are you gonna change row's label,button color or entire row style.. ? or do you want to change the row entire view to another layout xml ?

Comment: Hello Vishnu KR!
I have two imageViews and two textViews. Every time user click row i want one of this textVIews in every row change its text. But the problem is that another imageView get it's source via Picasso library. And every time I change the texts via notifyDataSetChanged or etc. Picasso updates the imageView, and it is visible to user. I want to prevent this from happening, so the question is : how can I change the specific view of row, without touching whole row

Comment: Haah.. you are saying that Picasso reloading the image right that time. So I think you need to use image caching technique. So the Picasso will not load the image again if it is already loaded. Or the next option is to block by show and hide the image by using a tag inside the item model

Comment: I'll take it into account, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use [Glide](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) (By Google) instead of Picasso. It's more efficient.

Secondly, your device won't download the same image again if it's already present inside your Cache memory.

Now,
Simply change the data inside your List and then update your adapter or recycler view.

Inside your AdapterClass

Create an Interface, let's say

```
public interface TheUpdater{
    public void updateMyAdapter(int position);
}
```

Then implement this interface in your Activity and override this method.

Now, in order to get the position of the View.

You can override `onClick()` of a View (Button or even the Whole Parent View i.e. Layout) and perform the following statement.

```
mTappedPosition = getAdapterPosition();

listener.updateMyAdapter(mTappedPosition); //Update the adapter
```

Where `mTappedPosition` is your global variable.

Inside your Activity

```
@Override
updateMyAdapter(int position){
---- //Do stuff
mAdapter.notifyItemSetChanged(position);
}
```

Comment: I know, but the problem is that I have ImageView that download source via Picasso, and every time I set notifyDatasetChanged  Picasso download the picture, and this update visible to user, I want to prevent that

Comment: Will you be able to get the position of the view inside the adapter? If yes, then I do have a solution for that.

Comment: Yes, i can get the position when i'm making the changes

Comment: One last question before I make an update to my answer. Are you gonna update the image on a click of a button inside the child view in RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code

```
 MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder= (MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder) recycleView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(1);
    viewHolder.txtView.SetText("Some Text");
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, it doesn't help

Comment: Okay, just one moment

Answer (score 0):

I think to avoid the image loading issue you have to use image caching technique. So that already loaded image won't be load again.

or

If the image is already loaded and each and every row is showing same image set then you can keep a boolean flag to your itemModel (The dto which has the adapter item's data ). and change that model and then call

```
 yourListToAdapter(index).setFlag(showImage1); // showImage1 boolean flag 

 yourAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
```